# Linux kernel 3.10.0-123.4.2 processes [flush] aren't present

Tags: linux, kernel

I am using [CentOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CentOS) 7 with "3.10.0-123.4.2.el7.x86_64" version, but I don't know why the kernel threads named `flush` aren't present in this kernel version.

I tried to look in the kernel change log, but I didn't find anything.

```
 [root@localhost ~]# ps aux | grep flush
 [root@localhost ~]# echo $?
 1
```

Without these kernel threads, how are the dirty data flushed?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are no more dedicated flush threads anymore.

The Linux kernel has moved on to a worker thread model, where several generic worker threads can handle a variety of different tasks. You will see these in the process list as `[kworker/#.##]`

Unfortunately this new design makes it [a bit difficult to tell exactly what any given kworker thread is doing](https://lkml.org/lkml/2011/3/31/68) at any given time. But you can rest assured that dirty pages are still being written to disk by *one or more* of the kworker threads.